# Rendering a Component Instance in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to render an instance of a Component Class from another Component Class in React. But for some reason, the browser complains that the component instance is not defined. I have it all in the same JS file (JS window in Codepen). Here's my code -

```
var NavBar = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var pages = ['home', 'blog', 'pics', 'bio', 'art', 'shop', 'about', 'contact'];
    var navLinks = pages.map((page) => {
      <a href="{'/' + page}">{page}</a>
    });

    return <nav>{navLinks}</nav>;
  }
});

var Page = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
        <div>
          <h1 className="text-primary">Welcome!</h1>
          <NavBar />
          <h2 className="text-primary">About Me</h2>
        </div>
      );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<Page />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Here's the app on [Codepen](http://codepen.io/Nyxx/pen/xRYREz?editors=1010). This is the error I get -

> pen.js:13 Uncaught ReferenceError: NavBar is not defined

I'm not quite sure what's going on. `NavBar` should be available in the scope of `Page`, as far as I understand.

Thanks!

Comment: For me it works well - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GNQNYp?editors=1010, only one note inside `.map` add `return` statement or use `pages.map((page) => (<a href="{'/' + page}">{page}</a>));`. Also don't forget add `key` for element inside loop

Comment: I see. I think I got confused with the concept of [implicit return in ES6 fat arrow](https://www.sitepoint.com/es6-arrow-functions-new-fat-concise-syntax-javascript/). I'm also not sure why the lack of `return` creates a problem here, when it seems to work here - `var multiply = (x, y) => x*y;`
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you mixed the function return approach and the fat arrow approach to return the map

when you use `{}` after the `=>` it means that whatever you are writing inside it is the body of the function. In that case you need to write a `return` statement like

```
var NavBar = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var pages = ['home', 'blog', 'pics', 'bio', 'art', 'shop', 'about', 'contact'];
    var navLinks = pages.map((page) => {
      return <a href="{'/' + page}">{page}</a>
    });

    return <nav>{navLinks}</nav>;
  }
});
```

The other way is to skip the function body and directly return the statement. It works well  because the map function only contains the return statement and if we skip the brackets and put the content in the parentesis then `JSX` will internally convet it into the `function body with a return` statement. It is much liuke the `lambda functions` being introduced in  `Java8`

You can use it like

```
var NavBar = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var pages = ['home', 'blog', 'pics', 'bio', 'art', 'shop', 'about', 'contact'];
    var navLinks = pages.map((page) => (<a href="{'/' + page}">{page}</a>));

    return <nav>{navLinks}</nav>;
  }
});
```

I suppose am I able to explain it properly

Comment: Yes, I understood it now! Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

```
var navLinks = pages.map((page) => <a href={'/' + page}>{page}</a>);
```

No curly braces, no `return` statement. I like [eslint](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/arrow-body-style) :)

Pen: http://codepen.io/free-soul/pen/dOdNby

---

Note that I also removed the surrounding double-quotes on the value passed to `href`.

Previously it was this: `<a href="{'/' + page}">{page}</a>`

for all values of page, the link url becomes : `www.example.com/{'/' + page}`

but I think you wanted it like this: `www.example.com/contact`. So no double-quotes.

Comment: Thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 0):

You have missed the return statement in the callback to map function. map function should always return a modified element of array.

Replace

```
<a href="{'/' + page}">{page}</a>
```

with

```
return (<a href="{'/' + page}">{page}</a>)
```